# Kotlin: Launching activity with companion using startActivityForResult

Tags: kotlin, startactivityforresult

I am building a countdown activity that needs to pass back the remaining time to the calling activity (when the countdown was only partially used.).

```
class CountDownActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object{
    const val REQUEST_START_COUNTDOWN: Int = 2

    fun CountDownIntent(iToDoRecord: iToDoRecord): Intent {
        return Intent(maincontext, CountDownActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_COUNTDOWN_TASK, iToDoRecord.itaskname)
            putExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_CALLING_DATE, MainActivity.currentDate)
            putExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_COUNTDOWN_TIME, iToDoRecord.itaskduration.toLong())
            putExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_COUNTDOWN_TASKID, iToDoRecord.itaskid)
            putExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_COUNTDOWN_TASKMILLI, iToDoRecord.itaskmilliremaining.toLong())
        }
    }
}.....
```

}

And then I call it from my reclyclerview like this:

```
 val intentitd = Intent(holder.textViewID.getContext(), CountDownActivity.CountDownIntent(currentiToDo)::class.java)
        //intentitd.putExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_CALLING_DATE, currentdate)
        startActivityForResult(CountDownActivity,CountDownActivity.CountDownIntent(currentiToDo),CountDownActivity.REQUEST_START_COUNTDOWN)
```

Compiler give me the following error:
"Type mismatch: inferred type is CountDownActivity.Companion but Activity was expected"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try calling the activity as:

```
val intent =  CountDownActivity.CountDownIntent(currentiToDo)

startActivityForResult(intent,CountDownActivity.REQUEST_START_COUNTDOWN)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried that, no luck. Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#startActivityForResult(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle) indicates that we need to use 
public static void startActivityForResult (Activity activity, 
                Intent intent, 
                int requestCode, 
                Bundle options)

Comment: It may be a problem of using context. Since you are trying to call it from inside the recycler adapter, you can try it as  :  ( holder.textViewID.getContext() as AppCompatActivity).startActivityForResult(intent, CountDownActivity.REQUEST_START_COUNTDOWN)

Comment: That nailed it, ACR! Sherlock Holmes genes.   Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help